# Is "prevent getting sick" a shorthand of "prevent yourself from getting sick"?

Tags: grammar

> Eat vegetables in order to prevent getting sick.

I am not sure if the above sentence is grammatical. I have seen the phrase "prevent getting sick", but I am not sure if you can just use like that anywhere, or there is a particular way to use it to make sure it's grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

In this case "getting sick" does not describe an action, it describes the end result. For example replace it with a more precise disease

> Eat vegetables in order to prevent scurvy.

Now the sentence makes sense again.
This way is somewhat odd and probably depends on the dialect of Engish you are speaking in.

Comment: There is nothing wrong—certainly not colloquially—with saying *to prevent getting sick*. In formal writing, it would likely be rephrased as *to prevent yourself from getting sick* or simply *to prevent sickness*.